# Spring Oauth antmatcher for /login does not work

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

My matchers looks like

```
http
    .anonymous().and()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers("/", "/login/", "/login")
    .permitAll()
    .anyRequest()
    .authenticated().and().csrf().disable();
```

When I'm trying to get data from url ***/login/*** everything works fine. But when I use only ***/login***, authentication is required.

Where Is a problem ? How do I have to write my matcher for a correct behaviour? (***/login*** and ***/login/*** is permited)

Comment: This is behaving correctly on my system!!

Comment: what do you get when you go to /login?

Comment: Application is redirect do Facebook login page.